# How to change hyperlink color in xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout

In my project I am not able to change the color of the hyperlink text.
Basically this text is shown in TextView and for it I have used xml layout such as 
 android:autoLink="all"

Now the problem is that I want to change the color of this hyperlink text to white

Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this property  `android:textColorLink="@android:color/white"` for that textView

Comment: Hello Pinki thanks for the answer. It's working in my code but only one problem can we change it's color when it is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still need to know this, put it here in case other people want to know.  If you want to change the link text color when it is clicked, just try this:

1 create **res/color** folder, create **linkcolor.xml** in this folder

2 put these code in **linkcolor.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FFFF0000"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#FFFF0000"/>
    <item android:color="#FF00FF00"/>
</selector>
```

3 for your **TextView**, just add:

```
android:textColorLink="@color/linkcolor"
```